# Iterative t-tests in dataframe with lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have a dataframe dataset30 with 38 variables. I wanna run t-tests for some of the 37 variables and group by the 38th variable...like this:

```
t.test (dataset30$Var1[which(dataset30$Var38 == 1)],dataset30$Var[which(dataset30$Var38 == 2)])
```

I messed around with lapply trying to iterate through all variables as a first step to a solution but failed:

```
lapply(dataset30, t.test(x[which(dataset30$Var38 == 1)],x[which(dataset30$ == 2)]))
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

Since no example given, I am going to use mtcars as dataset which is present in R environment.

```
mtcars_subst <- mtcars[,c("mpg", "drat", "hp", "am")] #Sample data
#Final code for running t.test
lapply(mtcars_subst[,c(1,2,3)], function(x)t.test(x ~ am, data=mtcars_subst))
 # iteratively running t.test on column mpg, drat and hp basis am as the category
```

**Updated after clarification:**

**Logic**:

Filtering the cyl values on 4 and 6 , There are in total of three categories in cyl (4,6 and 8) , to select only 4,6. I have used %in% here. Either you filter within lapply or subset the required data outside then use lapply.

```
mtcars_subst <- mtcars[,c("mpg", "drat", "hp", "cyl")]
lapply(mtcars_subst[mtcars_subst$cyl %in% c(4,6),c(1,2,3)], function(x)t.test(x ~ cyl, data=mtcars_subst[mtcars_subst$cyl %in% c(4,6),])) #comparing certain 2 groups
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! What would you do if your factor "am" was 3-staged and you wanted to test stage 2 vs 3?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. That´s why I specified the stages in the first code example in my original post. I have 3 stages and I want to test stage 1 versus stage 2 with a t-test.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!